# How are <pre> whitespace and line return "saved"?

Tags: javascript, html, carriage-return, pre, linefeed

If you want to toy with white-spaces, tabs, linefeed and carriage-return, how do you "*select them*" in javascript?

```
  x = $('pre').html().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "#");
```

***edit*** : **^Does <s>not</s> work** for linefeed and carriage-return.

Now, tabs are /(\t)/ and spaces are /( )/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example actually works.

http://jsfiddle.net/RSfN5/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could always escape the string then replace the escaped values - then unescape again - e.g.

```
<pre>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var str = "This is some\nJavascripty stuff with\nlinebreaks";
document.write(str);
var escStr = escape(str);
document.write('<br />');
noLineBreaks = escStr.replace(/%0A/g, "#");
document.write(unescape(noLineBreaks));
</script>
</pre>
```

Comment: It would be for user-filled `<pre>`. It can't contain javascript.

Comment: OK - probably did not explain myself well enough - try: alert(unescape(escape($('pre').html()).replace(/%0A/g,'#')));